# Execution expired doing Twitter gem queries with `sleep`

Tags: ruby, twitter, sleep

I am calling Twitter's `GET friends/ids` and `GET users/lookup` resources. They work great until I take rate limits into account. Here's an example of the working code:

```
def followers_ids(screen_name)
  cursor = "-1"
  followers_ids = []
  while cursor != 0 do
    followers = Twitter.follower_ids(screen_name, :cursor => cursor)

    cursor = followers.next_cursor
    followers_ids << followers.ids
  end
  followers_ids.flatten!
  followers_ids
end
```

When I throw a `sleep` into the while loop like so:

```
while cursor != 0 do
  followers = Twitter.follower_ids(screen_name, :cursor => cursor)

  cursor = followers.next_cursor
  followers_ids << followers.ids
  sleep(60)
end
```

I get different sets of errors at different times.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799in 'connect': execution expired (Twitter::Error::ClientError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in 'block in connect'
..
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:73:in 'perform_request'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:38:in 'call'
```

and

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/twitter-4.6.2/lib/twitter/response/raise_error.rb:21:in 'on_complete': Twitter is down or being upgraded (Twitter::Error:BadGateway)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:9:in 'block in call'
..
```

Anyone have any idea what could be going on? I had read somewhere that, when sleeping, your program will ignore all messages. Could this be part of it? Is there a better way I can be doing this?

Comment: Can you post more of the backtrace?

Comment: Thanks so much for your interest! Backtrace info updated in original post. Cheers!